# Not able to run Flight window application in UFT

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am using UFT trial version software. I have added username object to object repository (Object spy- UI automation mode). Below is the UFT code

```
SystemUtil.Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\samples\Flights Application\FlightsGUI"
Window("HP MyFlight Sample Application").WinEdit("agentName").Set "Username"
```

Below error i am getting

```
The test run cannot continue due to an unrecoverable error.

The "HP MyFlight Sample Application"  object was not found in the Object Repository.
Check the Object Repository to confirm that the object exists or to find the correct name for the object.

Line (2): "Window("HP MyFlight Sample Application").WinEdit("agentName").Set "Username"".
```

Image-
[Object repository image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoWLZ.png)

Please help!

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the object repository associated with the action

Comment: @Motti is correct...show that you have the correct name in the Object Repository.

Comment: Added plz check..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need to make sure that you have the object added to the object repository. You can check it quickly by typing window(, UFT will suggest the window names available in Object repository. Select the window object from there .This will also eliminate any additional typos which you might had.

2) Assuming that you downloaded the latest version of UFT, Flights GUI is now a WPF based application, so make sure that you have WPF addin selected before writing your tests or adding objects to repository.

3) I don't see .exe at the end of your application name, I don't know if that will cause any issues.

As everybody else suggested, if you can add the screenshot of your object repository, we should be able to help you.

Comment: selected activex,web, mobile, UI automation,VB plugins, Cant see WPF plugin.

Comment: You need to start the UFT setup again and once you reach the screen "Select the features to be installed", Select .Net WPF and Silverlight addins on this page. Complete the setup. Re-start the machine and after that your should see WPF and silverlight addins in UFT.